# Pass ID of the LINK on click from jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a follow/unfollow system like twitter. I tried several things from last two nights but I am unable to figure it out why the ID of an element is not passing through JQUERY to PHP.

Please help me to correct my code:

HTML:

```html
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default follow_user" id="<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>" title="Follow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Follow</a>
```

JQUERY:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '.follow_user', function(){
  if($(this).attr('title') == 'Follow'){
    $that = $(this);
    var ID=$that.attr('id');
    var action="follow";
    $.post('include/common/follow_user.php?user_id='+ID+'&action='+action,function(){
    $that.html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Following');
    $that.attr('title','Unfollow');
    $that.removeClass('btn btn-sm btn-default');
    $that.addClass('btn btn-sm btn-success');
   });
  }
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php session_start(); ob_start();?>
<?php $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];?>

<!-- Follow OR Unfollow User 
=============================================== -->
<?php
        include "../db.php";
        echo $follow_user=strip_tags(stripslashes(trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_id']))));
        echo $followee=$user_id;
        echo $action=strip_tags(stripslashes(trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['action']))));
        if ($action=='follow'){
            //follow
            $sql="insert into follow(follower_id,following_id,follow_date)values('$followee','$follow_user',UTC_TIMESTAMP())";
            if($con,$sql){}else{echo '<script type="text/javascript">toastr.error("We encountered a problem in doing that operation. Please try again after sometime.");</script>';}
        }else{}
?>
```

Comment: i think data should be sent like this $.post('include/common/follow_user.php,{user_id=ID,action=action},function(data,status){ alert(data); });

Comment: $.post('include/common/follow_user.php',{user_id:ID,action:ac‌​tion},function(data,‌​status){ alert(data); });

Comment: Thanks @JYoThI its working now :)

Comment: i posted my answer below . mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @dragonball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Data` should be sent like this for post method

```
$.post('include/common/follow_user.php',
       {user_id:ID,action:ac‌​tion},
       function(data,‌​status){ alert(data); 
      });
```

problem is your passing data as get method in url .but on server trying to get from post method . use get method .

```
$_GET['user_id']
```